# IQueryable<T> to List<T> performance issue

Tags: c#, iqueryable, generic-list

I have the following code that works fine, but I'm having some issue in terms of its performance. Through debugging, I can see that when the code comes to this line below, it takes 10 seconds to step through.

```
List<T> queryableListdResult = queryableInitialResult.ToList();
```

Basically this code below grabs about 15000 articles from 150000 records in the database.

Can someone please suggest a better way of doing this? Thanks!

My code:

```
        public static IQueryable<T> CategoryFilter<T>(IQueryable<T> queryable, int categoryFilterCount, RenderingContext rc, bool CategoryOR, string categoriesforQuery) where T : AbstractResult
        {


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoriesforQuery))
        {
            string[] categoriesDefined = categoriesforQuery.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            List<T> listInitialResult = new List<T>();


            foreach (string TaxonomyID in categoriesDefined) //e.g. entertainment, business
            {
                string categoryToCompare = TaxonomyID.ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
                queryable = queryable.Where(i => i.alltags.Contains(categoryToCompare));

                List<T> queryableListdResult = queryable.ToList();


                listInitialResult.AddRange(queryableListdResult);
            }
            if (CategoryOR)
            {
                return listInitialResult.AsQueryable();
            }
            else
            {
                List<T> queryableFinalResult = (listInitialResult.GroupBy(x => x._Group).Where(g => g.Count() >= categoryFilterCount)
                .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())).ToList();
                return queryableFinalResult.AsQueryable();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return queryable;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Suggested diagnosis tool. Run Sql Profiler to discover the actual sql generated by your call.

Comment: Do you need all those records or can you filter some out in the DB? Seems like an awful lot of data to return. I know you are filtering down already but still 15k records is a lot

Comment: @SCB No I don't need all these records, this is only the first step to filter the list.

Comment: Then I would continue applying filters to reduce the number of records rather than calling ToList on the IQueryable which will cause the query to be executed against your data store.

Comment: @SCB Good point, but I was having trouble to aggregate multiple IQueryables. So I cast to List then did an 'AddRange'...

Comment: How much data is in each row?

Comment: @Aron A news article basically, title synopsis, body etc. just text though.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from loading a truck load of data.
There are tricks to maximise EF context in terms of handling that.
eg `Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`

Your code snippet suggest the toList() might get executed each iteration.
You may like to work out a different way to get the

`List<T> queryableListdResult = queryableInitialResult.ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I took your code and I parallelized it.

```
public static IQueryable<T> CategoryFilter<T>(IQueryable<T> queryable1, int categoryFilterCount, RenderingContext rc, bool CategoryOR, string categoriesforQuery) where T : AbstractResult
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoriesforQuery))
        {
            string[] categoriesDefined = categoriesforQuery.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            ConcurrentBag<T> listInitialResult = new ConcurrentBag<T>();

            Parallel.ForEach(categoriesDefined, (TaxonomyID) =>
            {
                string categoryToCompare = TaxonomyID.ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
                var queryable = queryable.Where(i => i.alltags.Contains(categoryToCompare));

                List<T> queryableListdResult = queryable.ToList();


                for (int i = 0; i < queryableListdResult.Count; i++)
                {
                    listInitialResult.Add(queryableListdResult[i]);
                }
            });

            if (CategoryOR)
            {
                return listInitialResult.AsQueryable();
            }
            else
            {
                List<T> queryableFinalResult = (listInitialResult.GroupBy(x => x._Group).Where(g => g.Count() >= categoryFilterCount)
                .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())).ToList();
                return queryableFinalResult.AsQueryable();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return queryable;
        }
    }
```

Plus I used a concurrent bag which is implemented I believe in a LockLess matter. Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you check it against the original code to see if the performance improved?

Comment: Yes! I did it quickly on my laptop, which has only two cores and runs and not that great of a cycle frequency. But I still did see improvement by a factor of 1.8.

Comment: Seems reasonable, since without overhead you would expect a speedup of a factor of 2 on a dual-core machine.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but converting all the LINQ into basic functions would give you a speed up correct? And by basic functions I mean just using for's and if's.

Comment: There isn't a lot of overhead in Linq (Linq is basically `for` loops and `yield` statements under the hood), but there is some.  Any significant speedup would be due to [your ability to parallelize it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Extensions#Parallel_LINQ).

Comment: Doesn't yield have a bit of overheard? Since each state has to be stored in the state machine?

Comment: You have to store the state of the current loop in a `for` loop also.

Comment: True. Thanks for the mini lesson!

Comment: Linq is actually a deferred execution pipeline.  You can find out how it works in excruciating detail by examining Jon Skeet's [EduLinq](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) series.

Comment: Thanks guys, I can tell there is definitely improvements. I did a sql profiling and I can see thousands of the same query about 'getArticleItem' have been executed.

Comment: There should be no perf improvement. Linq to SQL and EF are not designed for multithreading.

Comment: Then how would you describe the method AsParallel()

Comment: @ArmenAghajanyan `.AsParallel()` is for CPU bound Linq queries. I assume that your laptop was connecting to a local database, in which case Network I/O wasn't the bottleneck, thus you were bottlenecking on the instanciation of the entities. However in the vast majority of cases your database is off box. Thus the main bottle neck is I/O. In this case given the OP calls his entities `Article` it is clear that the bottle neck is bandwidth in the I/O.

Comment: Okay. You are definitely right. My mistake, I though the OP was asking how increase his CPU performance.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider how much data you are querying. Assuming that each article has only 1kB of data. You are pulling down 15k entities, you are still trying to get 15MB of data from the database. Assuming a 10Mb/s link 10 seconds is pretty much right on the money in terms of data transfer rate.

I would suggest that you either project your query to avoid pulling unnecessary data or upgrading your data link.

However if what you need is your code to be more responsive, you could actually use a streaming `IEnumerable<T>`. You just use the `DbSet<T>.AsStreaming()` method. This will spread the cost of the data transfer across each call of `IEnumerator.Next()`. But I warn you the data transfer itself will take longer, and you will hold a datareader lock over the life of the transfer.

Just actually read your question more throughly. What you actually want is `IQueryable.Concat`. With that you can filter everything you want on each IQueryable, then concat them together, then finally `.ToList()` it.